# Cannot get specific content from regex

Tags: regex

I want extract from this javascript function the number `192`, this function is contained inside a string:

```
var jsFunction = "function loadMarkers()
{
    setMarker(
      "Stadio Giuseppe Meazza", 
      45.478083998442,
      9.1239792108536,
      null,
      null,
      192,
      null, 
      null, 
      null, 
      null,
      "/venues/italy/stadio-giuseppe-meazza---san-siro/v192/"
    );
}"
```

So I wrote this query: `loadMarkers[^\{]+(.*})`

this does not return any content, what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This RegEx captures a three digit number before the "/" at the end of a String.

```
 (\d{3})\/$
```